# Pass $@ to command, preserving quotes

Tags: bash

I am trying to amend the behavior of `git`, using the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16410521/38055), but I am stumbling on how to properly pass on the contents of `$@` without losing the quotes of the original input.

Basically, I have this:

```
# foo.sh

#!/bin/bash
cmd=$1
shift
args=$@
if [ $cmd == "bar" ]; then args=('--baz' "${args[@]}"); fi
echo git $cmd ${args[@]}
```

But when I run `./foo.sh bar -a "one two three"`, it outputs (and thus would have run), `./foo.sh bar --baz -a one two`, rather than `./foo.sh bar --baz -a "one two"` as I would have needed.

I can't figure out how to properly pass on `$@` to another command and preserve quoted arguments. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 15):

When using `"${args[@]}"` you assume that `args` is an array, but it's not.

For `args` to be an array, you must assign to it with an array assignment, such as

```
args=( "$@" )
```

To have the elements of the array individually quoted when you expand `${args[@]}`, you must double quote the expansion (just as with `"$@"`):

```
echo git "$cmd" "${args[@]}"
```

In this simple example, the separate `args` array is not really needed at all:

```
#!/bin/sh

cmd=$1
shift

if [ "$cmd" = "bar" ]; then
   set -- --baz "$@"
fi

echo git "$cmd" "$@"
```

Note that the quotes won't be outputted by the `echo` command above. But you can rest assured that `echo` gets exactly two arguments (`git` and `$cmd`) plus however many things are in `$@` at that point.  This is because the shell does quote removal on the command before executing it. You can compare this with what e.g. `echo "one two" three` outputs.

A better way to output the the command for visual inspection would maybe be

```
printf 'Arg: %s\n' git "$cmd" "$@"
```

This would print each separate argument to `printf` on its own line (prefixed by the string `Arg:`).

Your `git` command, `git "$cmd" "$@"` (or `git "$cmd" "${args[@]}"` if you use a separate array), would run correctly (given that the variables makes sense, ordinary `git` doesn't have a `bar` sub-command with a `--baz` option, for example).

Related:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)